# logger.error inside except block causes program to stop running?

Tags: python, logging, python-requests, request, python-logging

this is my first question here since I can't seem to find any information through google.

I have a function that sends a request to a service to obtain some information. The GET request is inside a try-except block in case the request times out or for any reason the service is unavailable. The code looks like this:

```
try:
   response = requests.get(service_url, timeout=2)
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as error:
   logger.error(f'Response from {service_url} is {error}')
   return some_object
```

What we want is that, if the service is unavailable, we still return an object similar to what the service would return, just with the "Unable to connect" message.

The problem I'm having is I'm trying to make sure that that "except" block works as expected and we properly return that object and log the error when the service is unavailable, but for some reason, when I reach the logger.error, it won't print anything and nothing returns at all. If I remove the logger.error, the whole function works as expected and the value is returned properly. If I put a logger.info or logger.debug before logger.error, the function will stop there.

Prints with "flush=True" work to print to the screen (note that if flush is not True, even prints won't print to the console), but for some reason logger.anything seems to not work at all. No error shows up, the app just stops there.

In case it matters, I'm using this to setup my logger:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

and I've tried assigning a log level of INFO to it, but still won't work. The python version I'm using is 3.7.12.

Any help would be appreciated. I can't figure out if the problem is actually the logger or what.

Comment: Does logging work in other places of the program?

Comment: It does. This specific service has different endpoints. The endpoint that calls this function is the one that seems to have issues with logging. The rest seem to work fine.

Comment: What if you replace logger.error with logger.info? Or with a print?

Comment: A print (provided it has flush=True) works. logger.info and logger.error have the same issue where nothing shows up in the console and the program just seems to stop, or at the very least it doesnt show anything else after that logger statement

For example if i replace that logger.error with logger.info and put a print with flush=True after that, the print won't print anything and nothing else will happen. If i remove the logger statement, everything works